# Unknown column...Как правильно сделать запрос на добавление в дочернюю таблицу значение с пробелом

Tags: mysql, веб-программирование, массивы, php, sql

```
$adstudent=("INSERT INTO `посещения` (`фио_студента`, `группа`, `дисциплина`, `тип_работы-занятия`, `дата`)
                            VALUES (`$stud_array[$st]`,`$g`,`$d`,`lecture`,`$lecdate[$num_date]`)");
                                                $studentsql=mysql_query($adstudent)or die(mysql_error());
```

> Unknown column 'Жук Роман' in 'field
> list'

почему так то?
заметил работая в navicat что по внешнему ключу в таблицу значение вставляется с двумя пробелами а выборка с одним

```
allstud=mysql_query("select `фио студента` from студенты where группа=$g") or die(mysql_error());
        #$stud=mysql_fetch_array($allstud);
        $i=1;
        $stud_array = array();
        while ($stud = mysql_fetch_array($allstud)) {
            $stud_array[$i] = $stud['фио студента'];
            $i+=1;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычки не те, нужны прямые:

```
('$stud_array[$st]','$g','$d','lecture','$lecdate[$num_date]')
```